# How to replace missing values using Mean and Standard Deviation in R?

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation

I have a data Set

```
X   Y   Z 
22  44  66
NA  67  89
42  45  98
NA  98  77
NA  63  33
65  54  78
89  67  90
87  78  83
NA  55  56
61  11  50
67  45  90
NA  90  43
90  43  76
```

Now, I want to replace NA values in Column X by "mean+StandardDeviation" and "mean-StandardDevaitaion" and that too randomly.
Can someone suggest a code for this?

Comment: Sorry do you mean you want to randomly assign NA values either `mean + stand. dev` or `mean - stand. dev`?

Comment: Do you need to do it by column? By row? By group?

Comment: Yes, I want to assign randomly [mean + stand. dev] or [mean - stand. dev] (mean and Std of column X) to null values in column X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate the values and randomly assign the value.
An example:

```
x <- c(22,NA,42,NA,NA,65,89,87,NA,61,67,NA,90)
x_mean <- mean(x, na.rm = T)
x_sd <- sd(x, na.rm = T)

values <- c(x_mean + x_sd, x_mean - x_sd)

set.seed(42)
n <- sum(is.na(x))

x[is.na(x)] <- sample(values, n, TRUE)
x
[1] 22.00000 89.52298 42.00000 89.52298 41.22702 65.00000 89.00000 87.00000 41.22702 61.00000
[11] 67.00000 89.52298 90.00000
```

Comment: Simpler: `sample(values, n, TRUE)`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Great idea, Updated the answer